# How to retrieve all values from DBCursor in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I do not know what are the attribute names in my collection.

```
DBCollection objDBC = db.getCollection(collectionName);
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
DBCursor cursor = objDBC.find(searchQuery);
```

Now from DBCursor how to retrieve values of all attributes?

Answer (score 4):

The [DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) is actually a result iterator, and every result element is a [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBObject.html) so it can be converted to a map; to retrieve all values you can do something like:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject resultElement = cursor.next();
    Map resultElementMap = resultElement.toMap();
    Collection resultValues = resultElementMap.values();
    //Do something with the values
}
```